# TextField with rounded corners : error text behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart

My Material TextField with Flutter looks like that :

[image: p1]

From this code (for the email TextField) :

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.primary,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        controller: _emailController,
        autocorrect: false,
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.email,
            color: AppColors.primaryPurple,
          ),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          errorText: _emptyEmail ? AppStrings.errorEmail : null,
          hintText: AppStrings.email,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

The problem is when showing error, this behaviour happens :

[image: p2]

Is there any way to fix this (so the error is below the TextField instead of expanding it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using decoration for container and that's the reason which is showing text error inside the box. You can give decoration to TextField as:

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
    ),
     filled: true,
     fillColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
     ),
),
```

Just remove the color of container and use filled in TextField

Answer (score 1):

The parent container must have the same background color of view and the textfield the primary color. Try this:

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundColor, // <--- change this
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        controller: _emailController,
        autocorrect: false,
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true, // <-- add filled
          fillColor: AppColors.primary, // <--- and this
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.email,
            color: AppColors.primaryPurple,
          ),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          errorText: _emptyEmail ? AppStrings.errorEmail : null,
          hintText: AppStrings.email,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```